# Automatically truncate source strings exceeding destination string size

Tags: sql, string, oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

I am writing a procedure that translates data from a vendor's tables into our local tables, and there are many assignments that map from a cursor on the source table into a `ROWTYPE` of the destination table. All of the vendor's string columns are defined with a size of 255, but our string columns are defined more stringently, usually only 30 or 50 characters. Certain of these mappings have thrown `VALUE_ERROR` exceptions when the source table's string is too long for the destination rowtype's column to accept.

The intended result is for the destination `ROWTYPE`'s column to contain as much as it can hold, and for the rest to be truncated. My first instinct was simply to use `SUBSTR` and hard-code the maximum size, but there must be a more elegant - and robust - solution.

One solution I've come up with (although it doesn't give me warm fuzzy feelings) is the below procedure, which simply handles the `VALUE_ERROR` exceptions and retries the mapping.

```
PROCEDURE p_safe_mapper(p_dest IN OUT VARCHAR2, p_out IN VARCHAR2) IS
counter INTEGER := 0;
  BEGIN
  --only loop for as many characters are in the source string
  WHILE counter < length(p_src) LOOP
    BEGIN
      --attempt to map, trimming COUNTER characters from the end of the source string. If it works, we're done.
      p_dest := substr(p_src,
                       0,
                       length(p_src) - counter);
      EXIT;
    EXCEPTION
      --else if we get an error, increment the counter to try again with the source string one character shorter.
      WHEN value_error THEN
        counter := counter + 1;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I've also considered querying `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` for the table column's size, but I don't know any way to get there from having a `ROWTYPE`.

Basically, since Oracle obviously knows the max size of my variables - be they `ROWTYPEs`, cursors, or plain old `VARCHAR2s` - I'm hoping to obtain a generalized procedure/function that can safely assign between any of them, truncating excess characters.

Comment: Very interesting question! I tried the `sys.anydata`+`sys.anytype` combo, but with no luck so far. I tried putting the `p_src` to a ref cursor selecting from `dual` and describing the cursor columns via `dbms_sql` ... with no luck, either. So far, the only "optimization" which comes to my mind would be that you do a binary search for the maximum string length instead of linear. :-)

Comment: I had also been looking into `anydata` and `anytype`, but I'm not familiar enough with them to have come up with anything yet. A few other people I work with had also suggested the binary search - if there isn't a better option, I will definitely implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two ways to do it - either

A) Change p_safe_mapper to accept a third parameter defining the max allowable output string size

or

B) Change p_safe_mapper to accept the destination table and column names, and use those to find the max size in one of the *_TAB_COLUMNS views.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Regarding option A, I definitely could do this with little trouble, but I'm trying to avoid having to hard-code the size. Regarding option B, is there a way to query the *_TAB_COLUMNS views for size data of ROWTYPEs, or cursors? Unfortunately, I'm not writing directly into the table, but into these other intermediate containers.

Comment: @TheDIMMReaper rowtype and cursor are PL/SQL constructs so I don't think you'll find any metadata for them. Instead you have to know the table and column.

Comment: @user272735 Thanks, that makes sense. Is there another way to arrive at similar data from a PL/SQL side, without necessarily knowing the table?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's nothing in PL/SQL which will give you the size of a variable or column.

Comment: @BobJarvis - I've implemented and used the non-warm-and-fuzzy solution in my question in production long ago, but I've still been hoping to one day have a better method. Regardless, your previous comment seems to be the final answer, that there is no way to get what I was looking for. Cheers!